# Remove all user folders except one on reboot

Tags: macos, script, automation

On a Mac, how can I create a script to automatically remove all user profile folders except a specific one on a reboot?

Comment: Hi Donna. Have you tried anything yet? Just to get the full picture: Why would you need something like this? Do the users still exist and are you planning to force-delete their profile folders?

Comment: This is for Macs in our university computer labs.  We don't want student profiles to stay on the Macs.  We use to add a few lines at the end of the periodic file in /usr/sbin to delete all folders in the User directory, but that also deleted our administrator account and the Shared folder.  I want to delete all profiles except our admin account (support) and the Shared folder upon reboot.

Comment: This is what was added to the end of the periodic file:

Comment: rm -r -f /users/*

mkdir /users/Shared

chmod 777 /users/Shared

Answer (score 1):

If you know how your administrator account is called, you can use Bash's `extglob` features to remove everything but that user profile. Here, we'll assume that the admin account is called `support`:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
rm -rf /Users/!(support|Shared)
```

The `!` inverts the matches.

To have a script run on logout you can [use a LogoutHook](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html) (but this is considered deprecated), or set up a `launchd` job that runs when OS X starts.