# Script to delete all non-admins with launchd or logout script on OS X

Tags: macos, bash, script, launchd

I've found a number of articles that touch on this subject but they are not running for me or perhaps because they are years old they do not work OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

In short we run Deep Freeze but I'd just like to have a script instead that runs either on a schedule at night every 24hrs or at startup that delete all user profiles that are not admins. Right now we have "administrator" & "root". The users logging in are active directory users.

Answer (score 0):

So I came across this https://superuser.com/a/552277/426602 and user @slhck may have the key I need! I added our "administrator" user and ran it and it worked great!

```
#!/bin/bash shopt -s extglob rm -rf /Users/!(administrator|Shared)
```

Now I'll try to put this into a launchd script to run at 3am everyday.